# Trailblazer: Which step caused my operation to fail?

Tags: ruby, trailblazer

Given an operation like

```
class MyOperation < Trailblazer::Operation
  step :do_a!
  step :do_b!

  def do_a(options, **)
    false
  end

  def do_b(options, **)
    true
  end
end
```

and the result of `run(MyOperation)`, how can I tell which step of the operation failed?

If the result object doesn't contain this info by default, what's a good way to add it?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? I would be curious, as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is this gem now which provides operation specific debugging utilities - https://github.com/trailblazer/trailblazer-developer

It allows you to see exactly which step raised the exception or which step caused the track to change from success to failure.

```rb
Trailblazer::Developer.wtf?(MyOperation, options)
```

It will print the trace of steps on STDOUT/Logger.

[image]

Comment: I think you can also debug with pry

Comment: Yes, but `wtf?` shows you immediately which steps failed, at any nested level.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the `trailblazer-developer` gem,
I would like to point out that you can handle failing steps with `failure` methods. 
In your controller use the helper `run` provided by `Trailblazer` that allows you to call an operation and inject the `result` (result object of the operation) in the controller, then you can access all of the `context` properties.

```
 # my_operation.rb
 class MyOperation < Trailblazer::Operation
   step :do_a
   failure :fail_a
    
   def fail_a(context, **)
     context[:error] = 'Step A failed.'
   end
  end

  # my_controller.rb
  class MyController < ApplicationController
    def do_a
      run MyOperation do
        return render json: { success: true }, status: :ok
      end

      render json: {
        success: false,
        error: result[:error]
      }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```